# L5: Class App\Http\Controllers\MessagesController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

В контроллере:

```
    public function destroy(Messages $message)
{
    $message->delete();
    return redirect()->route('messages.index')->with('message', 'Запись удалена.')
}
```

В виде:

```
   {!! Form::open(array('route'=>['messages.destroy',$message->id],'method'=>'DELETE')) !!}
       {!! Form::button('Удалить',['class'=>'btn btn-danger','type'=>'submit']) !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

В routes.php

```
    Route::post('messages.destroy', ['as' => 'messages.destroy', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@destroy']);
```

Ошибка на выходе:

ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\MessagesController does not exist

В чем проблема?

Comment: где контроллер лежит? как называеться? какой namespace,

Comment: Контроллер лежит в папке Http как и все контроллеры. MessagesController. namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: Если удалить содержимое destroy, ошибок нет.

Comment: Может поможет `composer install`?

Comment: И лучше обернуть `$message->delete();` в try...catch и обрабатывать возможную ошибку